# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found on visual studio online

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have seen this problem on several questions, all of the solutions work fine when you're building locally. I currently have my code on visualstudio.com, and I have an automatic build whenever I push code from my machine.

I know you have to install a nuget package (Which I have) and install the types from the following link:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409

The problem is, I don't know how to install that from my browser, since it's building in the cloud.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked the problem out with support from Microsoft.

It was quite simple actually, I have added the following line of code to the constructor of the `Context` object:

```
SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";
```

This came from a stackoverflow answer, but I have lost the link. If someone knows where this came from, feel free to comment the link, or mark as a duplicate.

Comment: Was Microsoft Supports answer to actually put that nasty string of text right into your code?  If that's the only way, I would at least recommend you put the string in  your config file.  When you go to deploy that to a server with v14 (or something besides 13.0.0.0) you'll see why.

Comment: this solution worked for me. @AdamPlocher is right though, this is a messy solution.

Answer (score 5):

After all tipps I found on the web didn't work out for me, I want do document the solution which worked for me:

I installed the Nuget Package and created the following redirect in app/web.config:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

I found the neccessary infos here:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/244

Answer (score 1):

I have found this to be a problem with both On-Premises TFS and VSTS.

Generally it look like this in VS:

[image: Folder tree of visual studio]

Even though it creates the folder in the bin directory locally it does not on the build server.

The first thing to do is to make sure that the `.dll` file are set to content and included in source control (they are often excluded by default). This should mean that they make it into the output directory. Because there are 32 and 64 bit dlls with the same name, you cannot rely on which version makes it to the actual bin folder, you have to maintain the same folder structure.

Once you have checked the build output directory you can call `SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies()` with the correct relative path.

In one instance I was referencing them in a project that was not the published project (a data access project) and the only way I could get it to work was to add the NuGet package to the top level published web project.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Onlines TFS Build Server doesn't allow you to install anything on it. You have to do it with a NuGet Package.

Add the SQL CLR Types dependency to your solution as a NuGet Package.

[image]

This way the build server will restore the NuGet package before the build:

[image]

If that doesn't work try the **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Unoffical** package.

<sub>Failing that I think you should raise this as a support case with Microsoft.</sub>

Comment: The unofficial package hasn't worked either. I have submitted a ticket with microsoft, thanks